# Getting custom-sized featured image's URL?

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I'm adding additional image sizes to my theme:

**functions.php**

```
add_image_size( 'my-thumbnails', 122, 122, true );
```

I used to get thumbnails URL like this:

```
wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
```

And it works like a charm, but I'm not sure how to display 'my-thumbnails' version of the thumbnail?

This doesn't work:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'my-thumbnails' );
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of the following:

```
// Thumbnail
wp_get_attachment_thumb_file( $GLOBALS['post']->ID );

// Custom
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size='my-thumbnails' );
// Or:
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size='my-thumbnails' );
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be $size='my-thumbnails' instead of $size='thumbnail' to answer the question fully correctly?

Comment: @MikeKormendy `thumbnail` is the default builtin value

Comment: I think we answered the question fully... My comment included.

Comment: You can edit and clean up comments. Comments are not part of the answer and only temp.

Comment: @MikeKormendy how about explaining what is the default?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the thumbnail as a featured image

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'my-thumbnails' );
```

Answer (score 0):

make your own function in function.php for display your images, then call it and put the size on the parameters of the function.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other way?

Comment: well, is the better way, no?, or what do you have in mind?